# How to upload background image in case of Google App Engine for WEB immediately using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have Google App Engine Web and Android application.We have admin part in which we have provision for client to upload their background images for WEB. We have coded and it is showing at local side but when I am deploying it app engine I am not able to see that updated image. I even stopped my database instance for a while but no use.If client updates background image for web then it should reflect immediately, but it is not happening. Can someone help me to understand how can we achieve it.

Thanks,

Prashant

Comment: It depends on how you serve your images. It can be caching issue or something totally different - it's impossible to tell without additional information.

Comment: There was cache issue. It is resolved now working absolutely smooth even uploaded on google app engine server. Thanks Andrei